# What expression represents the total cost?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

A customer calculated the cost of a new jacket , c, including a 7% sales tax, by multiplying 0.07 times the cost of the jacket and adding the product to the cost of the jacket. What is another way to calculate the price including tax? What expression represents the total cost?

Answer (score 2):

If you are adding $0.07c$ to $c$, then this can be written as either $0.07c + c$, or $1.07c$. Either one represents the total price, but $1.07c$ is fully simplified. Another way to do this problem is by simply multiplying $c$ by $1.07$.